# How to rank partitions by date order when values which I am partitioning on can repeat?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query which looks for the number of different values of a key field over a period of time and assigns a rank to the values in the order they occur.

So, for example I might have:

```
ID  Date          Value
1   2010-01-01    125.00
1   2010-02-01    125.00
1   2010-03-01    130.00
1   2010-04-01    131.00
1   2010-05-01    131.00
1   2010-06-01    131.00
1   2010-07-01    126.00
1   2010-08-01    140.00
```

I am using

```
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [ID] order by [Date]) as [row]
```

to rank the different values of the Value column in the date order they occur. So I would get something like

```
Value     row
125.00    1
130.00    2
131.00    3
126.00    4
etc
```

THe problem I am having is that sometimes a value might repeat. So in the above example if the value on 1st August was 125.00 for example. I want to treat this as a seperate occurance but using the ranking function I am using at the moment it obviously gets aggregated into a partition with the other instances of 125.00 when calculating the row number.

What's the easiest way for me to overcome this problem please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No it's just the ordering I need to know. So I basically need to generate a list of the [Value] each time the [Value] field changed, ranked in time order.   Responded to a comment which has been deleted! :-)

Comment: why are you doing this `partition by [ID], [Value]` instead of just `partition by [ID]` given that your query "looks for the number of different values of a key field over a period of time and assigns a rank to the values in the order they occur"

Comment: Sorry that was an error, I am only partitioning on [ID]. But that just ranks the rows in order without taking account of months where the value was the same as the previous month which I don't want

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
WITH A 
AS
(SELECT ID, [Date], [Value], ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [ID] order by [Value], [Date]) as [row] 
 FROM YourTable)

SELECT A.[Date], A.[Value], B.min_row as row
FROM A JOIN (SELECT ID, [Value], MIN([row]) AS min_row 
             FROM A) AS B
            ON  A.ID = B.ID AND A.[Value] = B.[Value]
```

Comment: Nope that doesn't seem to be working I'm afraid? That seems to end up returning all months and the same issue as in my question where different 'instances' of the same value have been grouped together even though there is a different value seperating them in time.